# Stop the lock screen! Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Tags: screen-timeout

How can I stop the lock screen locking itself every two minutes? How can I extend the time it takes to turn off automatically? I'm running Jelly Bean v 4.2.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S 4.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Display -> Sleep, and you can change the time out requirement from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timeout increased permanently, you can use the hint given in [TronicZomB's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45650/16575). But keep in mind that display is one one the heaviest battery consumers -- so if you often forget to turn off your display manually, your battery might last much shorter.

A more intelligent approach would be using some automation software like e.g. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), and have your display timeout set according to your situation. I use e.g. *Tasker* for that: when one of my reading apps (RSS, eBook, Web) runs in foreground, *Tasker* increases the display timeout to 3 minutes. As soon as I exit them (another app or the homescreen comes to foreground), display timeout is reset to 30 seconds.

Of course you can adjust those values to *your* needs. As a side effect, you will be able to automate a lot of additional stuff. For me, *Tasker* e.g. automatically activates GPS when I start some related app, and deactivates it afterwards (on 4.2, this will require your device to be rooted). It also switches WiFi off when I left home (and turns it back on when I return), and adjusts ringer/audio volumes when I'm in the office, plus more.